# Exact same count down timer hh:mm:ss for everyone

Tags: angular, countdowntimer, angular-moment

I'm using angular for auction site, calculating remaining time from auction end time using moment and showing counter, but it fails when user change his clock time.

Getting accurate time from server and calculate remaining time is good but after page loading, disturbing clock create issue, is there a way to get system clock changing event or check if user set auto sync/ internet time?

While getting remaining time from server also include network response delay and some other issues
Need to know best way to show **exact same timer** for everyone.

Comment: I would actually leave the clock as-is and allow the user to mess with it if they want (It's just a resource for them to know how long they have left). The enforcement comes from the server; if they bid, that needs to go to the server and the server should validate whether or not the bid is within the time limit.

Comment: I did same, all enforcement done on server side but still dont want to allow user to manipulate provided information

Comment: Great! Although it sounds like you're relying on user information on the server side, but for the time you should use your server's clock. So don't take the bid time from the http request, is what I'm saying.

Comment: Basically not relying on user information and also tried to use server clock by getting server time once and calculate diffrence between local and server time then adjust it in timer, the only issue is clock change after page load.

Comment: I use JavaScript server-side and it has built-in time functions. If you use UTC for all your calculations on server and client side that helps. Beyond that, I hope someone comes up with an actual answer to your question. But my experience tells me that there isn't one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try subscribe to document focus, and then get the dateTime form a server. After find the different between the date of client and the value.Some like

```
  inc: number = 0;
  timeInitial = 0;
  time;
  toogle: boolean = false;
  constructor(private timerService: TimerService) {}
  click() {
    this.toogle = !this.toogle;
    if (this.toogle) {
      fromEvent(document, "focus")
        .pipe(
          takeWhile(() => this.toogle),
          startWith(null),
          switchMap(() => {
            return this.timerService.getTime();
          })
        )
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.inc = new Date().getTime() - res.time;
          if (!this.timeInitial) this.timeInitial = res.timeInitial;
          console.log(this.inc, this.timeInitial);
        });

      timer(0, 1000)
        .pipe(
          takeWhile(() => this.toogle),
          map(() => {
            return (
              this.timeInitial -
              new Date(new Date().getTime() - this.inc).getTime()
            );
          })
        )
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.time = res;
        });
    } else {
      this.timeInitial = 0;
    }
  }
```

Your .html as

```
<button (click)="click()">{{toogle?'stop':'start'}}</button>
{{time |date:'H:mm:ss':'UTC'}}
```

And our service that make a call to a server that give us the date time, e.g.

```
export class TimerService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  getTime() {
    return this.httpClient
      .get("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Argentina/Salta")
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          const time = new Date(res.datetime).getTime();
          return {
            time: time,
            timeInitial: time + 30 * 60 * 1000
          };
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Well, if you change the time in your computer you see as the countdown change, but when you focus the app, the countdown re-calculate give you the correct time

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-45g1pb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)